# WebLogic Cluster - Restarting all app server instances on a weekly basis?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic

We are implementing a bespoke 3rd party J2EE application on a 6 server weblogic cluster (latest versions of Oracle products - running on SuSE). The supplier is suggesting to me that we schedule a restart of each WebLogic instance every week on a Monday morning at 3am.

I'm no weblogic expert and I can't seem to track down any best practice guidelines on the subject of regular restarts, but I'm used to working in environments where other clustered app server instances  have uptime is measured in much longer periods than 7 days...

My concern is that this is intended to mask issues in the J2EE app itself. Can anyone point me towards best practice guidance related to Weblogic which I may have missed, or confirm that this may be a legitimate suggestion from the application vendor?

Comment: I don't think there is any guidance on performing a "scheduled" restart. That sounds like a memory leak is being masked. Weblogic  doesn't come with a scheduling tool for starting/estarting servers. You could create a WLST script with a cron job... but...

Answer (score 0):

We don't always get perfect codes, no-wrong applications, and best programmers to work with you, in fact, many codes are written by junior programmers with low cost. So it is reasonable  there are some bugs in these J2EE applications (depend on OS patch level, java version, application itself, etc). Memory leak is one of the problem to ask regular restart to avoid the applications go down at business time. Some other problems are hide in and can't be easily found out.

That's the reason  to recommend to restart the application fortnight, weekly, or daily (I DO see some business java application restart every night).

If you really want to troubleshooting the application, maybe you can install some APM (application performance management) application to help you to find out why the application have memory leak, unstable behavior, etc.

You can search in google or read this URL for a starting : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management